# Doubt in Weinberg's book on QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, group-representations, s-matrix-theory, poincare-symmetry

In chapter 3 of his book on [QFT](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.fulviofrisone.com/attachments/article/453/Weinberg__The_Quantum_Theory_of_Fields_Volume_I__Foundations.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiRiK2E6IflAhWHr48KHQ8XDNkQFjAKegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw0oZWNCz9ONS83tirIVwSq9) (volume 1), while discussing the symmetries of the S-matrix, Weinberg makes the following statement

> For any proper orthochronous Lorentz transformation $x\rightarrow \Lambda x + a$, we may define a unitary operator $U(\Lambda, a)$ by specifying that it acts as in Eq.(3.1.1) on either the 'in' or the 'out' states.

(Equation 3.1.1 is basically the transformation law for a state vector under proper orthochronous Lorentz transformations, I'm leaving it out because it's extremely long). However, he had previously mentioned that the 'in' and 'out' states do not inhabit different Hilbert spaces. Then why, for a general Hamiltonian, can't the same unitary transformation act on both the 'in' and 'out' states?

Comment: "...it acts...on either the 'in' or the 'out' states" means that indeed the same transformation $U(\Lambda,a)$ can act on both the 'in' and the 'out' states. You're probably just misunderstanding Weinberg's sentence - 'Either...or' is not always an exclusive 'or' in colloquial English. (Also, whenever something you quote refers to "eq. (3.1.1)" so similar things, it's always good to also include the equation it refers to in your quote.)

Comment: My question us why can't it simultaneously act on both the 'in' and 'out' states. He very clearly mentions in the paragraph below equation 3.3.2 that for a general Hamiltonian, the $U(\Lambda,a)$ operator cannot act on both.

Comment: The operators $U$ act on both types of vectors and on every vector in the Hilbert space! The difference is that the action is the one expected on the momentum and the spin labeling the states only for the outgoing or the ingoing states with definite momentum and spin.

Comment: The reason is obvious: a multiparticle state with definite outgoing  asymptotic momenta and spins is not a state with definite ingoing  asymptotic momenta and spin just in view of the interaction. However,  due to general Poincare' covariace the two representations of the Poincare' group must be transformed one into the other by the S matrix.